# Why every set of positive measure has non-measurable subsets

Tags: measure-theory

> **Theorem:** If $A \subset \mathbb R$ and every subset of $A$ is Lebesgue measurable then $m(A)=0$
>
> **Corollary:** Every set of positive measure has non-measurable subsets

$m$ in here denote Lebesgue measure.

Why such corollary is true?

Comment: What is your question here? Why the second assertion is indeed a corollary of the first one? Or why the first assertion is true?

Comment: Why the second assertion is indeed a corollary of the first one?

Comment: It's the contrapositive of the preceding theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the following statements:
$$P=\text{"All subsets of $A$ are Lebesgue measurable"}\\Q="m(A) =0".$$
The theorem says that $P$ implies $Q$, in other words, the logical formula  $P\to Q$ is always true. On the other hand, we can always deduce from that the logical formula $\neg Q \to \neg P$ is also always true (if presence of $P$ implies presence of $Q$, then absence of $Q$ implies absence of $P$).

Now return to our meanings of $P$ and $Q$:
$$\neg P=\text{" $A$ has non-measurable subsets"}\\\neg Q="m(A) >0".$$

Therefore, the corollary: "Sets of positive measure have non-measurable subsets".